# Issue in reading mutilple files in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to read 1500 csv files ,but I am getting the below error.

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Code :

```
fi<-list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/DL/odi_csv_male",full.names=T)
dat<-lapply(fi,read.csv)
```

But When Individually open and save the file ,I am able to read the files.But as there are 1500 files I need to do it manually .Any help would be much appreciated ?

```
The file contains                                                                           version 1.3.0                           
    info    team    Ireland                     
    info    team    England                     
    info    gender  male                        
    info    season  2006                        
    info    date    6/13/2006                       
    info    venue   Civil Service Cricket Club, Stormont                        
    info    city    Belfast                     
    info    toss_winner England                     
    info    toss_decision   bat                     
    info    player_of_match ME Trescothick                      
    info    umpire  R Dill                      
    info    umpire  DB Hair                     
    info    match_referee   CH Lloyd                        
    info    winner  England                     
    info    winner_runs 38                      
    ball    1   0.1 England ME Trescothick  EC Joyce    DT Johnston 0   0
    ball    1   0.2 England ME Trescothick  EC Joyce    DT Johnston 0   0
    ball    1   0.3 England ME Trescothick  EC Joyce    DT Johnston 0   4
```

Comment: One of your files is probably malformatted. `lapply(fi, function(f){print(f);read.csv(f)})` will print each file name out as it reads it in. Last file printed in the problem file

Comment: How to resolve this?

Comment: Try `lapply(fi, read.csv, row.names = NULL)`.

Comment: It gives error Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '1000887.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: if I open each file and save it csv then I am able to read it.Its time consuming

Comment: or Is there any way to automatically open each file and save it in csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread` from `data.table` is more robust IMO.

Try

```
library(data.table)
dat<-lapply(fi,fread)
```

It might also happen that some of your files are not in `.csv` format. Try adding:

```
fi<-fi[grepl(".csv",fi)]
```

Or, as commented, the option `row.names=NULL` could help in `dat<-lapply(fi,function(x) read.csv(x, row.names=NULL))`

If the data is unstructured, try with `fill=T`

```
dat<-lapply(fi,function(x) fread(x, fill=T))
```

EDIT: Please note that it is normal (and advised) for `dat` to be a `list` in this case, because `dat` consists of many `data.frames`. Try indexing your list appropriately using `[[]]`.
In case you *really* don't want lists, you could use:

```
for(i in 1:length(fi)) {
 name <- paste0("dat",i)
 myvar <- data.frame(fread(fi[i], fill=T))
 assign(name,myvar, .GlobalEnv)
}
```

After that you'd have many data frames called dat1, dat2...

EDIT: after chat, the issue was related to the plotting and aggregation of the files, not the reading and the problem is solved

Comment: There is no error but Its only reading the first 20 columns ,As the data is unstructured , I Mean for first 20 rows I have only 4 columns ,whereas after 20 rows the data has 25 coumns.

Comment: Its working ,but data is converted into lists .After reading I am plotting it .But now I am not  able to plot it

Comment: for(i in 1:length(fi)) {
  name <- paste0("dat",i)
  assign(data.frame(fread(fi[i], fill=T)) ,name, .GlobalEnv)
}

Comment: This gives following error Error in assign(data.frame(fread(fi[i], fill = T)), name, .GlobalEnv) : 
  invalid first argument

Comment: see answer should work now, you should give the variable name first and then the variable itself

Comment: Its not working,I have edited the question to share you the contains of the files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182290/discussion-between-gpier-and-praveen-chougale).